# Dynamically edit a link to change video source

Tags: javascript, html, video

I am trying to make a page where I can dynamically change `<video>` source link by inputting an episode number.

Here is an example:
[Example of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNE2m.png)

And here is the code I have at the moment:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#button').click(function(e) {  
        var inputvalue = $("#input").val();
        window.location.replace("http://www.example.com/episode/"+inputvalue+"/somemoretext.mp4");

    });
});
```

```html
<div><input type="text" value="Episode Number" id="input"> 
<button type="button" class='btn' id="button">Watch</button></div>

<video width="100%" controls="controls">
<source src="http://www.example.com/episode/24/somemoretext.mp4">
Your browser does not support this video's playback.
</video>
```

I would like the javascript to change the url of the video tag instead of the button.

Comment: `$('source').attr('src', "http://www.example.com/episode/"+inputvalue+"/somemoretext.mp4");`

Comment: Thank you! I will paste my final code below.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me thanks to @Tushar

```js
$('#button').on({
    'click': function(){
    var inputvalue = $("#input").val();
    $('#videot').attr('src', "http://example.com/episode/" + inputvalue + "/something.mp4");
    }
});
```

```html
<div>
<input type="text" value="Episode Number" id="input">
<button type="button" class='btn' id="button">Watch</button>
</div>

<video id='videot' width="100%" controls="controls">
<source src="http://example.com/episode/25/something.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support this video's playback.</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the following Snippet, there are 5 videos.

1. The click event was changed to to delegate click event (`.on`)
2. The `episode` was assigned the value of `#input` and converted to a real Number.
3. The video API doesn't understand what a jQuery object is so we must us plain JavaScript to reference the `<video>`
4. Next we change the `src` property of `<video/source>` (when targeting a `<video>` that has a `<source>` we can target either one regardless of which element actually has the attribute).
5. Last step is to `load()` the new url of the `src` property. This is necessary when the `src` is changed.

**Note:** I added `$('#counter').val(episode)` just because it looks neat but it's not necessary.

#### SNIPPET

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#button').on('click', function(e) {
    var episode = Number($("#input").val());
    $('#counter').val(episode);
    var vid = document.getElementById('vid1');
    vid.src = 'http://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/av/vid' + episode + '.mp4';
    vid.load();
    vid.play();

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Video Episode:
    <output id='counter'></output>
  </legend>
  <input type="number" value="Episode Number" id="input" style='width:4ex' min='1' max='5'>
  <button type="button" class='btn' id="button">Watch</button>
</fieldset>

<video id="vid1" class="vid" style='width: 90vw;' controls>
  <source src="http://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/av/vid1.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
</video>
```